# Drupal 7 create node with Date Repeat Entity programmatically

Tags: drupal-7

I'm using module date repeate entity. I already have had start/end datetime, rrule. How do I create repeating nodes from them programmatically?
With admin interface, I can create repeating nodes correctly. How do I do without using the admin interface?

Answer (score 0):

Try [node clone](https://www.drupal.org/project/node_clone) module.

It provides function to clone from a node programatically.

Comment: I've already using module Replicate to clone node programmatically. My questions here how to calculate **and** create repeating nodes?

Comment: I would create a cron job which runs a query to find out the nodes scheduled for cloning last 10 minutes and run that cron every 10 minutes.

Answer (score 0):

1. Calculate repeating date

From library php-rrule https://github.com/rlanvin/php-rrule

Use class `RRule` for simple repeating date: frequency, start date, interval and number of repeating

Use class `RSet` when you want to combine multiple RRule, include or exclude dates

Results will be date object

2. Save result into field date time of node ex

```
foreach ($rrule as $occurrence ) {
  echo $occurrence->format('Y-m-d'),"\n";
}
```